# How to add footer view in a Horizontal List View

Tags: android

I am using a Horizontal List View
 https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView
library, I need to set a footer view on it.How can i set it.

Comment: library broken link!

Comment: I change the link. @hasan83

Comment: It is not supported for this view. See Javadoc "Does not support header or footer views". I would embed this view in a linear layout and add header and footer on top and bottom of the listview.

Comment: If any other way to make a horizontal list view with footer view than please let me know. @hasan83

Comment: Do you want the footer to be at bottom or at the right? since this a horizontal list? if at bottom do as @ThomasR. suggested. just put a linear layout after the list view. it will behave as expected.

Comment: For list view it works ,but i need to add it on a horizontal list view and it is not going to support.@ThomasR.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't understood my comment. I mean something like this:

```
<LinearLayout with vertical orientation>
  <HeaderView/>
  <HorizontalListView/>
  <FooterView/>
</End of LinearLayout>
```